# I want to let my text box allow only text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I'm working on project using MVC3 + Razor.I want to let my text box allow only text. I tried to apply data annotation in my data model (First Code):

```
[DataType(DataType.Text ,ErrorMessage ="Error")]
```

but, it's not working.Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a regular expression as below:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Please input letters only")]
```

Comment: I think now it's working, thank you but there is a problem, the error message is not showing up in the form

Comment: @Fahda.Shalhoub You must show yourself if your regular expression return false value

Comment: @Fahda.Shalhoub Please show your view code. And don' forget to mark if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You could annotate your model like this:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]
string TextBoxData {get; set;}
```

Then in your view you would use the helper

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TextBoxData)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TextBoxData )
```

Comment: Yes, I did the same things in the view and model but still the error  message is not showing

Comment: Please help to provide the code so that I able to see where is problem.